# A problem in communicating with raspberry pi

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,

```
I want to use rosserial package to communicate with raspberry pi by wifi . Do I have to install ROS on raspberry pi? Is there a better way? Please help me, thanks. :))
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202654/a-problem-in-communicating-with-raspberry-pi./) by [travis](https://answers.ros.org/users/21197/travis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-02-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to use wifi it probably makes sense to install ROS on the pi and leverage the power of that. If you want a simple serial connection from the pi to ROS running on a different computer then a different radio infrastruture would make more sense - like zigbee, or one of the many pairs of radio modules that you send serial in one, and it comes out of the other.

---

Originally posted by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) with karma: 1504 on 2015-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0